# View pager returns black screen

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager that displays GPUImageViews. When creating instances for each page, everything seems great. The problem comes when I tried swiping backwards, to load the previous page. Here's my onCreateView code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //I store my previous pages in an imageArray variable to prevent application from rendering image over and over again.
    temp = imageArray[this.index]; //temp is a GPUImageView; assume initialized
    if (temp.getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup) temp.getParent()).removeView(temp);
    }
    temp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    return temp;
}
```

When I added `removeView()` the view pager always return black screen. I tried taking off the `removeView()` but then it always gives me the error "child view has existing parent...remove parent view first."

EDIT: 
to be more specific, i added my onCreate(), init() and renderImage() functions. by the way, this is a Fragment and for my PagerAdapter i'm using FragmentPagerAdapter

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.saveBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.init();
    this.renderImage();
}

private void init() {
    temp = new GPUImageView(getActivity());
    this.img = new GPUImageView(getActivity()); //the original image
    this.img.setImage(imgUri);
}

private void renderImage() {
    temp = this.img;
    temp.setFilter(Filter.setFilter(getActivity(), this.filterPosition));
    temp.requestRender();
    imageArray[this.filterPosition] = temp;
}
```

I tried debugging to see how my app works...It seems like when creating new instances, onCreate() will always be called followed by onCreateView().  Based from the lifecycle of this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), I thought only onCreateView() will be called repeatedly.

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet ? I am facing the Same problem in my `HorizontalListView`

Comment: @SalmanMuhammadAyub Sorry, no I didn't solve this. I settled for an easier design rather than having a view pager.